# Objective-C: `continue` in collection enumeration block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

If I have an NSArray and I use `enumerateUsingBlock` to loop through elements in the array, but in some cases I need to skip the loop body and go to next element, is there any `continue` equivalent in block, or can I use `continue` directly?

Thanks!

update:

Just want to clarify, what I want to do is:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    if (i == 5)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // do something with i
}
```

what I need is the `continue` equivalent in block.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A block is a lot like an anonymous function. So you can use

> return

to exit from the function with return type void.

Comment: Hi please see my update for what I meant, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, but isn't `return` the equivalent of `break` in a standard loop? If so, then what's the equivalent of `continue`? `break` breaks me out of the loop entirely, while `continue` jumps to the next iteration. How do you do that in an enumeration block?

Comment: `return` *without* `*stop = YES` is equivalent to `continue` in a for loop. `return` *with* `*stop = YES` is equivalent to `break`.

Answer (score 10):

Use "continue" when using Fast Enumeration to do this.

Sample code:

```
NSArray *myStuff = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A", @"B",@"Puppies", @"C", @"D", nil];

for (NSString *myThing in myStuff) {
    if ([myThing isEqualToString:@"Puppies"]) {
        continue;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",myThing);

}
```

and output:

```
2015-05-14 12:19:10.422 test[6083:207] A
2015-05-14 12:19:10.423 test[6083:207] B
2015-05-14 12:19:10.423 test[6083:207] C
2015-05-14 12:19:10.424 test[6083:207] D
```

Not a puppy in sight.

Answer (score 5):

You can not use continue in block, you will get  `error: continue statement not within a loop`. use return;

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        /* Do something with |obj|. */
        if (idx==1) {
            return;
    }
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    }];
```